# Qt Quick Controls Styles ReferenceError

Tags: qt, qml

I want to isolate the style of my components in a file like "ComponentStyle.qml" (Qt5)

#### ComponentSyle.qml

```
Item {
    id:root

    Component {
        id: touchStyle
        ButtonStyle {
                ....
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: switchStyle
        SwitchStyle {
                ....
        }
    }

}
```

So, in my main.qml, I want to use the style like :

#### main.qml

```
    ...
    Button {
        style: touchStyle
        text: "Press me"
        width: parent.width
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
```

But, it wont work ! I have some errors :

> file:///C:/Qt/5.2.0/msvc2012/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Switch.qml:133: TypeError: Type error
>   file:///C:/Qt/5.2.0/msvc2012/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:92: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

main.qml:60: ReferenceError: touchStyle is not defined*

Is someone can help me ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think I would have to see more of your ComponentStyle.qml but I think you're missing properties.

You should use these two links to get an overall idea of how to format you code for themes and styles.

[Styling](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-usecase-styling.html) - Has great examples on styling text and buttons very applicable to your case.

[QmlStyling](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QmlStyling) - Lists different approaches and techniques for implementing styling.

I hope that helps.